# Can files be recovered after a failed mv command?

Tags: unix, data-recovery, mv

I used `mv * ..` in Unix to move all contents of a directory to its parent folder. There was a folder called "Downloads" in both the current directory and the parent. The one in the parent was empty to begin with.

After executing this command, I was back to a command prompt, but the shell had frozen, and I had to start a new SSH session. Now, the Downloads folder in the parent directory is still empty, and the Downloads folder I was trying to move no longer exists.

Is there a way to find out where these files are, or at this point is is a data recovery program necessary to find the files, since nothing is pointing to them in the filesystem anymore?

Comment: Could you see any directory in the same folder just after you ran the command? Try to browse the remaining directories and look for the files inside.

Answer (score 4):

You may want to run a filesystem check in case some nodes went missing:

```
fsck -fyv /dev/sdaX
```

You should change `sdaX` for your actual partition. But as far as I know, if a file is removed, it's gone forever. That's why I always run `cp` and when I see everything is ok I run `rm`. You can also try with data recovery tools, but it's not 100% guaranteed that you recover everything. *Once you go blank you never go back*.

Answer (score 1):

You need to be careful with **mv** and **cp**: they are unforgiving, and you can easily lose files, eg:-

```
mv * ..    ; # moves from current directory to parent, overwriting duplicates
```

I recommend always using **-n** or **-i** to prevent overwrites. I also suggest **-v** to list what was done. I once mistyped (I caught the # key, next to return on my keyboard):-

```
mv * other/#
```

This moved the first file to 'other/#', then overwrote the same '#' with every other file, leaving me with only '#', containing the last file moved! I've not done that again.

Because I also use TCC on Windows I have typed, unthinkingly expecting to move to files of the same name in the target directory:-

```
mv -iv * other/*    ; # In TCC, MOVE * other\* would do what I wanted
```

This normally fails, unless the last expanded name in the target is a directory, in which case all the files in the current directory *and all the other files in the target* are moved to it.

As for what happened to your files: if you know any of their names, use **find** from the parent directory to see if you moved them somewhere unexpected. If that doesn't work, try the parent's parent. You might be surprised at where they ended up.

If you don't trust yourself to remember the options, add the following command (or similar) to either **~/.bashrc** or **~/.bash_aliases**:-

```
alias mv="`which mv` -iv"
```

Comment: So mv * .. should overwrite? It's odd because the original empty directory is what seems to be there.

Comment: Yes, **mv** does overwrite silently by default, though it will prompt for confirmation if the destination file is not write-enabled.

I can't explain why you would lose all your files: I would expect a disc or network failure to lose only the file being moved at the time, though it's possible that it would continue after a failure to keep moving files and give the same error on each. I cannot easily check this.

Note that moving a directory implicitly moves all the files and subdirectories under it.